# Gnuplot: Variables of multi-column stats

Tags: statistics, gnuplot

I'm computing the statistics of a file where the 2nd column is my X-value and the 15th column is my Y-value. This works fine as long as the x-range covers the whole data in the file.

```
stats '$LOGFILE' using 15 name 'rate_Y_'
print rate_Y_max
```

outputs this:

```
* FILE: 
  Records:      74
  Out of range:  0
  Invalid:       0
  Blank:         0
  Data Blocks:   1

* COLUMN: 
  Mean:      26391.9815
  Std Dev:   37555.9366
  Sum:      1.95301e+06
  Sum Sq.:  1.55917e+11

  Minimum:    2793.2603 [ 1]
  Maximum:  142755.0813 [73]
  Quartile:   4586.2274 
  Median:    10359.6168 
  Quartile:  27017.6600

142755.081306
```

But when I want to limit the x-range, I have to define my X-column

```
set xrange [40:400]
stats '$LOGFILE' using 2:15 name 'rate_Y_'
```

and get a two-dimensional statistic and my variable rate_Y_max is not accessible any more:

```
* FILE: 
  Records:      7
  Out of range: 67
  Invalid:      0
  Blank:        0
  Data Blocks:  1

* COLUMNS:
  Mean:        182.1429       111416.6321
  Std Dev:     118.5585        14491.4560
  Sum:        1275.0000       779916.4248
  Sum Sq.:  330625.0000       8.83657e+10

  Minimum:      50.0000 [6]    83292.6937 [0]
  Maximum:     400.0000 [0]   124953.1493 [5]
  Quartile:     75.0000        99960.3747
  Median:      150.0000       111045.6078
  Quartile:    300.0000       124912.0550

  Linear Model: y = -120 x + 1.333e+05
  Correlation:  r = -0.9817
  Sum xy:       1.302e+08

           line 0: undefined variable: rate_Y_max
```

*Question*: How do I access two-dimensional statistic variables?

Answer (score 3):

Use `show variables rate_` to see all variables that were generated by you call to `stats ... name 'rate'`.

```
set xrange [0:100]
stats '+' using 1:($1**2) name 'rate'
```

Now call `show variables rate_` which prints

```
Variables beginning with rate_:
...
rate_min_x = 0.0
rate_max_x = 100.0
...
rate_min_y = 0.0
rate_max_y = 10000.0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

From the doc :

> If two columns are analysed jointly by a single stats command, the
>   suffix "_x" or "_y" is appended to each variable name. I.e. STATS_min_x
>   is the minimum value found in the first column, while STATS_min_y is
>   the minimum value found in the second column.

So

```
rate_Y_max_y
```

Is what you're looking for.

You probably should use :

```
stats '$LOGFILE' using 2:15 name 'rate'
print rate_max_y
```

Comment: LOL. 3 years later, I come back to this post and want to upvote it, before realizing I'm the one who also had this problem and wrote an answer for it already.